# Linked list insert method ,without using packages

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I want implement a method that looks for a movie with a given id and inserts a new object after it, I've been trying for so long please any help is appreciated, below is the my latest attempt, with a `getMethod` for a movie that takes an id and returns a movie.

```
public Movie getMovie(int id) {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getData().getId() == id) {
            return current.getData();
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean insertAfter(Movie m, int id) {
    Node movieNode = new Node(getMovie(id));
    Node current = head;
    Node pre = null;

    while (current != null && current.getNext().getData().getId() != movieNode.getData().getId()) {
        pre = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    movieNode.setNext(current);
    if (pre == null) {
        head = movieNode;
    } else {
        pre.setNext(movieNode);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: it wont insert object after the given id

Comment: List is a solved problem in java.  Read the API and use it.

Comment: Start up your debugger and single-step the program. Look at the values at each iteration of your `while` loop. You'll find the error pretty quickly. It's kind of unclear what you're trying to do. You say that you're trying to find a movie with a given id and insert something after it, but your `insertAfter` code looks like you're trying to insert a movie with the same id. You need to edit your question and tell us more clearly what you're trying to do, and also describe the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @DwB He clearly said that he's trying to do it without using packages. Whereas it's true that linked list is a solved problem, it's still useful to understand how to implement it.